# Does the cache stop working after a certain time?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, redis

Describe the situation.

There is a site with news, news has several relationships, and several count requests, because the site can go for a few seconds about 100+ people, it was decided to use the cache, namely, redis (predis/predis).

Everything works fine, pages are loaded with lightning, but after about an hour of work-the news are no longer given through the Cache, and begin to request directly from the database (https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5eDI.png). If you restart the server-the situation is normalized, but after a while everything will repeat when there are too many requests-the server just gives 502. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsMZ0.png)

What could it be?

Redis setting is standard, except that the memory is increased to 32GB.

Comment: What is your code for storing the item in cache?

Comment: @levi Default laravel cache facade, something like:

   Cache::remember(key,minutes, function () {
      return $db->select(...)
   });